# Change of basis: find the coordinates of the point relative to the coordinate system.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, change-of-basis

This is the complete problem:

[image]

The solution:

[image]

I tried to find out why -v1' = (2/3)v1 + (1/3)v2 but I still don't get it. If anyone can help me, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate $v_1'$ you have to find other vectors that compose $v_1'$. Since $\frac{|\overrightarrow{BD}|}{|\overrightarrow{DC}|} = \frac{1}{2}$ you get 
$v_1' = \frac{1}{3} \overrightarrow{CB} - v_1$. With $\overrightarrow{CB} = -v_2 + v_1$ you get
$$v_1' = \frac{1}{3}(-v_2 + v_1) - v_1 = -\frac{1}{3}v_2 - \frac{2}{3} v_1$$